# Msfvenom new formats ?

Tags: metasploit

can someone explain to me the difference between  exe, exe-only, exe-service, exe-small   and  msi, msi-nouac in msfvenom  when generating payload for  privilege escalation ?

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just different wrappers for Windows ShellCode:

- **exe** : standard PE format for Windows
- **exe-only**: *not sure on this on, never used it...*
- **exe-service**: runs as a service instead of a process
- **exe-small**: creates smallest version of ShellCode (may include bad chars). Used for tight buffers
- **msi**: wraps an executable in an MSI for auto execution when run
- **msi-nouac**: MSI with no UAC

Comment: Msi-nouac gives me SYSTEM  in "always install elevated" exploitation for privilege escalation while msi gives me just user rights ,, so msi-nouac search for installation with system privilege  ...it's not really goes  with intuition

Comment: Depending on the user access level (i.e. administrator), if UAC is disabled / DNE, it should spawn a shell as SYSTEM. What type of exploit are you using?

Comment: MSI packages can be installed with elevated privileges for non-admin users. For a package to use elevated privileges the a registry name “AlwaysInstallElevated” must exist in both keys with a dword value of 1. we can abuse this setting to elevate our privilege but it works when I make a payload with -f msi-nouac if I use just -f msi it gives me the normal user right

Comment: Ok now i see what you're trying to say, you're not triggering the payload through an exploit your running it standalone.